# What is the minimium amount of employees in an office for it to be called "bullpen"

Tags: word-usage

I work in a company in which each department has its own office in which there are 4 desks with 8 computers and 8 chairs, so 2 people sit at a single desk. Each of these rooms has its own printer. Can these offices be called bullpens or are they too small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullpen) gives as sense 3 of "bullpen":

  > an open work area not divided into offices
- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bullpen) gives:

  > a large open area in a place such as an office, where many people stand or work: *Enclosed individual offices are increasingly being replaced by open offices, bullpens, or cubicles.*
- [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bullpen) gives:

  > a large room in an office occupied by many employees.
- [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bullpen) gives as sense 3:

  > An open area in an office with workspace for a number of employees.

Note that none of these specifies any particular number. Some specify "many" or "a large number". Whether eight employees at four desks constitute "a large number" is a judgement call.

One should also note that "bullpen" in this sense often carries a negative nuance. It is a term often used by employees complaining about such a pattern. A different term, such as "shared office" or "team work room" might be better. But "bullpen" cannot be called **wrong** in the suggested use. There is no specific minimum number which makes a work area a bullpen.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bullpen) (disregarding the specialized senses for baseball etc.):

> a large open area in a place such as an office, where many people stand or work. [From Cambridge Dictionary]

If the area is open (i.e. without cubicles) then sure, one such office with eight people could be a bullpen. [I have seen other definitions which suggest bullpens are specifically for *junior* employees, but this seems not to be a widespread use].

**However**, even in the US where the phrase is more common, it is still relatively rare. In particular, I have never heard the plural (*bullpens*) used for offices. You should also know that it's a relatively informal term, being originally a baseball term.

Comment: In the UK, we tend to call that layout 'open plan' and there is very often no segregation by grade.